# Is State<T> only designed for @Composable in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have read [the article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state),

It seems that `State<T>` is designed for `@Composable`.

Is it better to use `State<T>` in other classes such as `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, being part of the `androidx.compose.runtime` package `State<T>` was indeed intended as a value holder for **composables**.

If you want to publish/emit and consume "states" within **ViewModels** or **Composables** you might want to take a look at [StateFlow and SharedFlow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow)

You can either `collect` those as you would with any kotlin `Flow<T>` and use `collectAsState` within compose functions.

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable() {
    val myState by viewModel.stats.collectAsState()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

States trigger recomposable, for each screen I've always used custom data class (if it's necessary) and wrap it inside mutableStateOf(YourDataClass()) and place it in ViewModel just like we always use LiveData. And in your screen (composable) you can just `val yourState = viewModel.yourState.value`.

For a complete example

```
// ViewModel

private val _yourState: MutableState<AnimeTopState> = mutableStateOf(YourState())
val yourState: State<YourState> = _yourState

// ViewModel



// Composable

val yourState = viewModel.yourState.value

// Composable
```

So, state is like the way to trigger view changes on @Composable function, we cant just trigger view change with `LiveData` or normal value like the way we used to with XML view.